# When I install electron on mac i have got permission denied message

Tags: node.js, electron

```
  MacdeMacBook-Air-5:electron-api-demos Mac$ sudo npm install

> electron-chromedriver@1.6.0 install /usr/local/yanxi/electron-api-demos/node_modules/electron-chromedriver
> node ./download-chromedriver.js

/usr/local/yanxi/electron-api-demos/node_modules/electron-chromedriver/download-chromedriver.js:16
  if (error != null) throw error
                     ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/yanxi/electron-api-demos/node_modules/electron-chromedriver/electron-tmp-download-7487-1515139845145'
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! electron-chromedriver@1.6.0 install: `node ./download-chromedriver.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the electron-chromedriver@1.6.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/Mac/.npm/_logs/2018-01-05T08_10_45_423Z-debug.log
```

It show that I have no permission
I have try many methord to solve this problem but do not work!
I have  use cmd :
 `sudo chmod 777 .`
 `sudo chown -R nodody:nobody ./*`

Attention: I did it on mac platform!

Comment: You should format your code, it's pretty unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

Try running your NPM install like this:

`npm install --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root`

Explanations of the NPM config flags used above can be found here:
https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config